# how to iterate through json result in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a function in ruby on rails, where I make a call and get the following json data. now i want to add another “key” : "value" to each item in the json data and return the new or modified json object from the function. what is the best way to do this in ruby?

```
def get_results
  results = getJsonData(); 
end 

[
  {    "name" : "Harry Potter",  "rating" : 1,  }, 
  {    "name" : "Lord of the rings",  "rating" : 2,  }, 
  {    "name" : "game of thrones",  "rating" : 3,  }, 
]
```

Comment: Hint: [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each).

Comment: In Ruby you do not, and should not use `;` at the end of statements. That's reserved for situations where you need multiple statements on one line. You should also omit empty argument lists.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to transform every element of a collection

```
def get_results
  results = getJsonData(); 
  results.map { |item| item.merge("year" => 2000) }
end
```

In this case I'm adding a key `"year"` to your hashes with value `2000`, it depends what you want to do

Comment: Using `merge` here seems kind of wasteful unless the original data must be preserved. Why not `item['year'] = 2000`?

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right, but I don't know what the user wants to do

Comment: I might be reading too much into this, but data pulled from a JSON file is usually "owned" by the method that loaded it, affording significant freedom here.

Comment: @Ursus - thanks, yes I do want to preserve all the key/value pairs in the response, and then add more to it.

Comment: @Ursus - one minor detail. It turns out, I have to do response.data to get the json array of objects.

Comment: It's not very clear here what getJsonData returns, it's hard to help you. can you open another question giving us more details?

Comment: getJsonData is calling another api, and I tested it such that when I do results.data, i get the array similar to one in my question.

Comment: @Ursus - so I probably need to change it to results.data.map? as results.data is the array?

Comment: your problem is not clear. It's not even clear if that `get_results` is an action or a simple method. open a new question